# Include model relationships in json response using Eloquent and Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a Model setup as so:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Upload extends Model {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'uploads';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('id', 'user', 'created_at', 'updated_at');

    public function mime() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Mime', 'mime');
    }
}
```

And when `JsonSerialize()` is called, it returns:

```
{
    "serverPath": "upload/2015/06/06/21/filename.jpg",
    "filename": "filename.jpg",
    "mime": "92"
}
```

This `92` references the id in another table (which `App\Models\Mime` represents) with a string, `type`, associated with it. I would like to replace this `92` with said string.

```
{
    "serverPath": "upload/2015/06/06/21/filename.jpg",
    "filename": "filename.jpg",
    "mime": "image/jpeg"
}
```

How is this possible? I tried some stuff with `protected $appends` in the `Upload` model, but I'm not sure I fully understand how to use/access relationships from within the model.

**Clarification** The table *mimes* contains columns `id` and `type`, while table *uploads* contains an integer column called `mime` that references an id in *mimes*

Comment: I'd just say ->with('mime') when I'm returning it - does that help? For example `return \Upload::find(1)->with('mime');`

Comment: Where would something like that go? You mean when I'm returning the `Upload` model in another function? `\App\Models\Upload::findOrFail(1)->with('mime')` returns just `{}` when `JsonSerialize` is called on it

Comment: Well how are you returning it now? Please update your question with this as it might give better context. Also, could you try not calling JsonSerialize I think all Eloquent models are automatically converted to JSON, or you can do `->toJson()` on an Eloquent model.

Comment: This is all part of an API that does `return new JsonResponse($data)`. So it's more or less doing `return new JsonResponse(\App\Models\Upload::findOrFail(1))`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It is not a good idea to name a relationship the same name as one of the fields on the table. This causes issues (as you've found out) when trying to access the relationship versus accessing the field.

Ideally, your `mime` field should be renamed to `mime_id`. This conforms to Laravel's conventions, and is a more accurate name for the field.

However, if you don't have the ability to change the name of the field, you should change the name of the relationship.

```
class Upload extends Model {
    protected $hidden = array('id', 'user', 'created_at', 'updated_at');

    public function uploadMime() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Mime', 'mime');
    }
}
```

In the class above, the relationship name is now `uploadMime`. Additionally, the relationship was changed from a `hasOne` to a `belongsTo`. Since your uploads table has the foreign key to the mimes table, the Upload model belongsTo the Mime model (and the Mime model hasOne/hasMany Upload models).

Now, your code should look something like:

```
$data = \App\Models\Upload::with('uploadMime')->findOrFail(1);
return new JsonResponse($data);
```

This should give you output something along the lines of:

```
{
    "serverPath": "upload/2015/06/06/21/filename.jpg",
    "filename": "filename.jpg",
    "mime": "92",
    "uploadMime": {
        "id": 92,
        "type": "image/jpeg"
    }
}
```

**Modifying JSON using `$appends` and attribute accessors**

If you wanted to get closer to the JSON output you've provided in your question, you can create a `mimeType` accessor and add it to the `$appends` property:

```
class Upload extends Model {
    // hide the mime field and uploadMime data
    protected $hidden = array('id', 'user', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'mime', 'uploadMime');

    // add the mimeType attribute to the array
    protected $appends = array('mimeType');

    // code for $this->mimeType attribute
    public function getMimeTypeAttribute($value) {
        $mimeType = null;
        if ($this->uploadMime) {
            $mimeType = $this->uploadMime->type;
        }
        return $mimeType;
    }

    public function uploadMime() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Mime', 'mime');
    }
}
```

This should give you output something along the lines of:

```
{
    "serverPath": "upload/2015/06/06/21/filename.jpg",
    "filename": "filename.jpg",
    "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
}
```

**Modifying JSON by overriding the `toArray()` function**

Or, if you really want the JSON to use the `mime` key, you can modify the `toArray()` method directly:

```
class Upload extends Model {
    // hide uploadMime data, but not the mime field
    protected $hidden = array('id', 'user', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'uploadMime');

    public function uploadMime() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Mime', 'mime');
    }

    // override the toArray function (called by toJson)
    public function toArray() {
        // get the original array to be displayed
        $data = parent::toArray();

        // change the value of the 'mime' key
        if ($this->uploadMime) {
            $data['mime'] = $this->uploadMime->type;
        } else {
            $data['mime'] = null;
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

This should give you output something along the lines of:

```
{
    "serverPath": "upload/2015/06/06/21/filename.jpg",
    "filename": "filename.jpg",
    "mime": "image/jpeg"
}
```

Comment: is this applicable in 5.2?

Comment: @user3779015 yes, the information here is still relevant for 5.2.

Comment: Wouldn't accessing a model relationship within the `getMimeTypeAttribute` accessor or the `toArray` mutator potentially create an `n+1` problem? Such as in `Upload::all()`.

Comment: @Soulriser Simply retrieving the records will not cause an `n+1` problem, as the accessor is not called until the fake field is accessed. However, if you retrieve the records, and then do something to access the fake field for all those records, that will cause the `n+1` issue, if you didn't eager load the dependent relationship. You can either add the dependent relationship to the `$with` model attribute, or just make sure to always eager load the relationship when you will be accessing your fake property.

Comment: @patricus That still means that in your example calling `toArray()` will create `n+1`, regardless of whether or not you access the custom property, unless you always eager load the related model in advance. In this case it might be better if the `get()` and `all()` methods could eager load the related model by default, perhaps by overloading the parent methods, but I'm not familiar enough with Eloquent to know how/if that could be done.

Comment: @patricus I looked into this a bit more, and I'd suggest adding `if ($this->relationLoaded('uploadMime')) { ... }` as a condition around the loading of the related model. That would avoid potential `n+1` issues, since you won't end up loading the related model unless it has already been explicitly eager loaded.

Comment: I am having the same issue but with a collection. The example presented here is using a single entity versus a collection. Could you please help me on how I could do this for a collection using paginate!

Answer (score 2):

Okay I believe this is what you're looking for ...

**Upload.php** (no changes here)

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Upload extends Model {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'uploads';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('id', 'user', 'created_at', 'updated_at');

    public function mime() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Mime', 'mime');
    }
}
```

Then you have your Mime model

**Mime.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Mime extends Model {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'mimes';

}
```

if you do this for a test I believe you should see the type

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('test', function() {
    $upload = \Upload::with('mime')->first();
    // return $upload //here would return it as JSON I'm pretty sure!
    return $upload->mime->type;
});
```

Check docs for further details on eager loading: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: This is returning the error: QueryException in Connection.php line 624:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'mimes.mime' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `mimes` where `mimes`.`mime` in (826)). If it helps, the table `mimes` contains columns `id` and `type`, while `uploads` contains an integer column called `mime` that references an `id` in `mimes`

Comment: Changed the relationship to `return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Mime', 'id', 'mime');` which fixed the SQL error. Though the issue now is that `$upload->mime` is not an object, but just the id.

Comment: Check out @partricus answer, it's exactly what I'd update my answer too if he hadn't already posted it