# Laravel - Return related models of parameter in controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent, routes

I have the following route:

```
Route::get('/api/products/{product}', 'ProductController@get');
```

My Product model looks like this:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredient::class)->withPivot('value');
    }
}
```

In my controller, the method is:

```
public function get(Product $product)
{
    return $product;
}
```

This only returns the attributes of the `Product` object as a JSON. I would also like to return the related ingredients and pivot table values (as it would with the `with` method), and possibly other related models.

`return $product->with('ingredients')` creates a collection of all Products, so that doesn't really work, I have to filter it again by the product ID. I can obviously construct the JSON myself, but that becomes tedious if I want multiple related models included. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you sure you can't access it via `$product->ingredients()`?
In Laravel, models are kinda interchangeable between text form (json) and code form (php object).

Comment: @JCode Sorry, it's possible the question wasn't quite clear. I can return the list of ingredients with `return $product->ingredients`, but I would like to include that list next to the basic parameters of the product, so the resulting JSON would look something like this: `{"id": 1, "name": "MyProduct", "ingredients": [...]}` (without having to construct the JSON myself).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688076/include-model-relationships-in-json-response-using-eloquent-and-laravel-5

Comment: is this any similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Using `$with` in model

   ```
   class Product extends Model
   {
       protected $with = ['ingredients'];
       public function ingredients()
       {
           return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredient::class)->withPivot('value');
       }
   }
   ```
2. Load the relation and return product:

   ```
   public function get(Product $product)
   {
       $product->ingredients;
       return $product;
   }
   ```
3. Use the `load` method on the product:

   ```
   public function get(Product $product) 
   {
       return $product->load('ingredients'); 
   }
   ```

Comment: I think this is gonna work. To make it a bit simpler, we can also write like this in the controller:

public function get(Product $product)
{
    return $product->load('ingredients');
}

Comment: Thank you for your answers @KevinBui and @AnasBakro! These are all great solutions, I added the one from the comments to the answer to make it easier to find. (Also I find the second option really unintiutive, but it works nonetheless :D)